# Mixing name orders in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a situation where I need to cite names (with biblatex) in both East Asian order and Western order, such that the bibliography lists an entry like 'Smith, John and Yamada Tarou' or 'Yamada Tarou and John Smith', but in-line citations list it as 'Smith and Yamada'. I know how to change name orders globally (with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` and so on), but is it possible to change them on an individual basis?

Comment: You could force "Yamada Tarou" via `author = {Smith, John and {Yamada Tarou}}` (and maybe define `shortauthor` if need be). I think `biblatex` is not really capable of dealing with Eastern names in a satisfying fashion. Changing the name format for one name, though, seems very complicated, after all how is `biblatex` to know where to change the format.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting to have to use some kind of workaround. `shortauthor` seems like a good solution (if you don't use it, it ends up as 'Smith and Yamada Tarou', which is weird).

Comment: This solution is working quite well, thank you! Put your comment in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `biblatex` is as of now only able to deal with western names in a satisfying fashion. In particular, `biblatex` assumes names to have a "first last" format where "first" is the given name and "last" the family name.

We can use a kind of ugly hack in this situation. Just put the East Asian name into curly braces, `biblatex` will then treat this name as one unit (not consisting of any first or last names). To obtain only the family name in citations, use the `shortauthor` field, add Western style names as before and just the family name of the Eastern Asian name.

```
author = {Smith, John and {Yamada Tarou}},
shortauthor = {Smith, John and Yamada},
```

Comment: Apparently, using a `shortauthor` including a Western-order authors confuses `biblatex`, so that you'll have to specify a `shortauthor` field for any Western-order authors whose names appear in collaboration with Eastern-order authors. Following the above Smith and Yamada example, citations for any other book written by Smith will appear as 'J. Smith' unless you specify a `shortauthor` field for all of them.

Comment: @Sjiveru Ahh, yes that is thanks to the `uniuequename` feature.

Comment: @Sjiveru Found a fix! Give the full name of Smith in the `shortauthor` field, *only* shorten the East Asian name. So it's `shortauthor = {Smith, John and Yamada}`.